# Check for Header Row in Uploaded Excel file Classic ASP

Tags: excel, asp-classic

I am uploading and connecting to an Excel spreadsheet.  So far, so good, I am able to read through all rows in it, and do what I need.

What I am facing now is sometimes I may have the same data layout, but no header row.

How can I make the determination if the 1st row in the spreadsheet is a header row or not?

This is using classic asp (I know uggg...), and ADODB.Connection

Comment: Could you post some code to show us where you have  got to? Also for the record there is nothing wrong with [tag:asp-classic] just miss understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the `HDR` setting of the [Microsoft Jet OLE DB Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681754%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

- `HDR=Yes` (*default*) indicates that the the Jet provider will not include the 1st row in the record set.
- `HDR=No` indicates that the Jet provider will include the 1st row in the record set.

You may supply a value for `HDR` in your connection string. For a reference, see http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/.

It seems that the Jet provider can detect whether or not the spreadsheet contains a header.

- If the spreadsheet contains a header, the Jet provider captures the header as is.
- If the spreadsheet doesn't contain a header, the Jet provider automatically labels the fields as `F1`, `F2`, `F3` and so on.

Whether the header is given in the spreadsheet or generated by the Jet provider, it's the `HDR` setting that enables you to include the header or leave it off the retrieved record set.

Comment: I thought this as well... however, if the spreadsheet does not contain a header row, won't the engine automatically skip the first row due to the HDR flag in the connection string?  In otherwords... the same structured spreadsheet may or may not contain a header row